# Error: Undefined variable cwtplot in Scilab

Tags: signal-processing, scilab, wavelet

I try to analyze 3-d image of the wavelet transform of the signal (image is obtained using the mesh function)
Then I want to get my 2-d image of the wavelet transform using the cwtplot function.

```
cwtplot(signal, 1:32)
```

However, scilab shows an error

```
Undefined variable cwtplot
```

Comment: cwtplot is not a standard Scilab function. Are you using a toolbox ?

Comment: Yeah, I`ve installed all necessary packages

Comment: Which toolbox ?

Comment: I guess you have a broken install of the Scilab Wavelet Toolbox. It has not been ported to latest Scilab version (6.1.1). How did you ended up to install it ?

Comment: from here https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/swt/0.3.0.1, and then I installed it through scilab console

Comment: Please tell if you succeeded with the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new version 0.3.2 of the Atoms module "Scilab Wavelet Toolbox". It was just a matter of recompilation (+some other small fixes). If you update the Atoms database you should be able to download it:

```
--> atomsSystemUpdate
--> atomsInstall swt
--> atomsLoad swt

 Start swt toolbox - (0.3.2)
    Load macros
    Load gateways
    Load help
    Load demos
```

The page of the updated Atoms is there: https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/swt/0.3.2 and here is a screenshoft of the cwtplot help page example:

[image]